# dplyr is not working inside function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I don't have experience on functions in R. I'm trying to build one that calculates the mean by a target variable (in my example: funded_final).

My data:

```
residential_status  funded_final
Living with parents 0
Rent                0
Rent                0
Own                 1
Own                 0
Own                 0
Rent                0
Rent                0
Rent                0
Living with parents 0
Rent                0
Rent                0
Rent                1
```

When I do this outside the function works great

```
test2 %>% group_by(residential_status) %>% 
summarise(tar_average = round((mean(funded_final, na.rm=TRUE))*100,2),N =     n()) %>% arrange(desc(tar_average)) %>% mutate(Perc = round((N/sum(N))*100,2),Cum_Perc = cumsum(Perc))%>% print(n = nrow(.))
```

The results:

```
 residential_status tar_average     N  Perc Cum_Perc
           <fctr>       <dbl> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
1                 Own       33.33     3 23.08    23.08
2                Rent       12.50     8 61.54    84.62
3 Living with parents        0.00     2 15.38   100.00
```

When I use the function, I just get the total average:

```
 group.by.func <- function(dataframe,target){ dataframe %>%group_by(residential_status) %>% 
summarise(tar_average = round((mean(target, na.rm=TRUE))*100,2),N = n()) %>%
arrange(desc(tar_average)) %>%
mutate(Perc = round((N/sum(N))*100,2),Cum_Perc = cumsum(Perc))%>%
print(n = nrow(.))}
group.by.func(test2,test2$funded_final)
```

Results:

```
residential_status tar_average     N  Perc Cum_Perc
           <fctr>       <dbl> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Living with parents       15.38     2 15.38    15.38
2                 Own       15.38     3 23.08    38.46
3                Rent       15.38     8 61.54   100.00
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `dplyr::summarise` uses non-standard evaluation and expects the names of the columns as unquoted strings. In your case, the variable `target` is not a column name but a vector containing the values of the column. The function has no way of associating the vector with the data.frame. Therefore, the grouping does not apply to the vector `target`. In each evaluation of the grouped data.frame, the mean is taken over the entire vector `target`.

You could solve it by passing the column name as a string and using the 'standard evaluation' version of `dplyr::summarise`:

```
group.by.func <- function(dataframe, target){ 
    dataframe %>% group_by(residential_status) %>% 
            summarise_(.dots = list(
                            tar_average = paste0("round((mean(", target,", na.rm=TRUE))*100,2)"), 
                        N = "n()")) %>%
        arrange(desc(tar_average)) %>%
        mutate(Perc = round((N/sum(N))*100,2),Cum_Perc = cumsum(Perc))%>%
        print(n = nrow(.))
}
group.by.func(test2,"funded_final")
```

Results:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
   residential_status tar_average     N  Perc Cum_Perc
               <fctr>       <dbl> <int> <dbl>    <dbl>
1                 Own       33.33     3 23.08    23.08
2                Rent       12.50     8 61.54    84.62
3 Living with parents        0.00     2 15.38   100.00
```

Comment: Great! :) Thank you very much @ikop

Comment: Hi @ikop, if I need to put one more argument in my function (for example for residential status) should I do the same? I'm sorry, but I'm a little confused with this NSE stuff. Thank you

Comment: Just define a second target argument in your function (e.g. `target1` and `target2`). Inside your call to `summarise_`, construct your evaluation string using `paste` and add it as an additional list element in `.dots`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ikop